# Struct attribute changed after usage

Tags: c, visual-c++

In the following example, once we access the `bar` attribute its value automatically changes.

```
typedef struct {
    DWORD bar;
} MYTYPE;

void Create(LPVOID *myTypePtr)
{
    MYTYPE myType;
    myType.bar = 50;
    *myTypePtr = &myType;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DWORD foo;
    MYTYPE *fooPtr;

    Create((LPVOID)&foo);
    fooPtr = (MYTYPE*)foo;

    printf("%d\n", fooPtr->bar);  // This prints 50 (ok).
    printf("%d\n", fooPtr->bar);  // This prints 2147344384 (garbage).

    return 0;
}
```

Yes, the structure must be passed as a void pointer. I'm probably missing some conversion detail but I can't get it. Compiling with Visual C++ 2003.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function `Create`, you are making the argument `myTypePtr` point to a local automatic variable `myType`. The variable `myType` is out of scope when the function exits, so it's undefined behavior to dereference the pointer that points to it after the function exits.